# UNICODE ERROR: converting value to float in Python

Tags: python, pandas, unicode, gspread

I'm pulling in some data from a google spreadsheet in python via gpread, the data is stored in a pandas dataframe.

I'm trying to calculate a metric by dividing two columns the dataframe:

```
df['a']/df['b']
```

This returns the error

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'float' and 'unicode'
```

I tried changing it to a float:

```
df['a'].astype(float)
```

But i get the error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 2,217.93
```

I figured commas might be the problem, so i tried to remove them

```
df['a'] = df['a'].replace(',', '').astype(float)
```

but i get the same error when trying to convert it to float.

When i do:

```
df.applymap(np.isreal)
```

It says the columns within the dataframe i pulled from the Google Spreadsheet aren't real, but the columns i got from elsewhere are real.

Looks like gspread/googlesheets-api is converting all my values to unicode. Can someone suggest how i might convert them to float?

Comment: Did you assign it back? `df['a'] = df['a'].replace(',', '').astype(float)`?

Comment: Yes i did.  Edited to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes had types error while playing with dataframe. I now always run this line before and no error are now raised.

```py
# Convert all columns that can be converted into float into float.
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore')
```

Comment: can you write the code to create the same (or a sample) of the dataframe you are using ?  It will be easier for us to recreate your issue

Comment: I managed to solve it by casting values to float before joining the dataframes. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question because I managed to solve it.

The `df` in the question is a result of joining two dataframes - `df1` has data pulled from a database, `df2` has data from pulled via the googlesheet (gspread) API.

Previously I had tried to cast the values in `df` to a float but to no avail. I then changed cast values in `df2` to float BEFORE the join and it worked.